# Lazy initialization vs. eager initialization in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, initialization, instantiation

I'm just wondering which type of initialization should I use for when creating components in a frame.

Let's say I have a frame that contains several buttons:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private JTextField dynamicText; // accessible

    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents()
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        dynamicText = getText();
        JButton open = createButton();
        JButton close = createButton();
        close.setEnabled(false);

        add(open);
        add(close);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton createButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton();
        // some customizations, like size, icons etc.
        return button;
    }

    private JTextField getText() {
        if (this.dynamicText== null) {
            this.dynamicText= new JTextField();
            // some customization
        }
        return this.dynamicText;
    }

    public void updateText() {
        // code to update dynamicText
    }
}
```

Is this a good way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any point to doing it this way. The components are still going to get initialized as soon as the object is created, so you don't gain anything from this.

Comment: I am just wondering which one makes the code more readable and easier to debug, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice depends on your display requirements and the initialization delay. To have the best user experience, a general recommendation would be to consider lazy initialization for components that take time to be filled in or are not immediately required in the display. Otherwise, stick with eager initialization for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take in consideration the following factor to decide what strategy is the best to use:

- If initialization process take a long time you can initialize it in asynchronously before using it
- If the JFrame is rarely used you can consider to initialize it on demand
- If the JFrame is dynamic initialize it on demand
- To create a more readable code use an eager approach
- If the JFrame is not too heavy and is often used use an eager approach